Using LineRenderer to draw lines on a sphere
I am trying to draw lines on a globe like the scientific software app GPlates. In GPlates you draw polygons on a globe by clicking on the globe to place vertices.
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MousePosition : MonoBehaviour
{

    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public float radius = 1.0f; // The radius of your sphere
    //public Vector2[] geoCoordinates; // Array of (latitude, longitude) points
    public int numSegments = 100; // Number of segments for smoothness

    private Vector3 prevHit;
    
    void DrawCurvedLineOnSphere(Vector3 startPoint, Vector3 endPoint)
    {
        List<Vector3> linePoints = new List<Vector3>();

            // Interpolate along the great circle path using Slerp
            for (int j = 0; j <= numSegments; j++)
            {
                float t = (float)j / (float)numSegments;
                Vector3 interpolatedPoint = Vector3.Slerp(startPoint, endPoint, t);
                linePoints.Add(interpolatedPoint);
            }

        // Set the LineRenderer points
        lineRenderer.positionCount = linePoints.Count;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(linePoints.ToArray());
    }

    Vector3 ConvertGeoToCartesian(float latitude, float longitude, float radius)
    {
        // Convert degrees to radians
        float latRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * latitude;
        float lonRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * longitude;

        // Calculate Cartesian coordinates
        float x = radius * Mathf.Cos(latRad) * Mathf.Cos(lonRad);
        float y = radius * Mathf.Sin(latRad);
        float z = radius * Mathf.Cos(latRad) * Mathf.Sin(lonRad);

        return new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
    
    public Vector2 ToSpherical(Vector3 position)
    {
        // Convert to a unit vector so our y coordinate is in the range -1...1.
        position = position.normalized;

        // The vertical coordinate (y) varies as the sine of latitude, not the cosine.
        float lat = Mathf.Asin(position.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        // Use the 2-argument arctangent, which will correctly handle all four quadrants.
        float lon = Mathf.Atan2(position.x, position.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        // Here I'm assuming (0, 0, 1) = 0 degrees longitude, and (1, 0, 0) = +90.
        // You can exchange/negate the components to get a different longitude convention.

        Debug.Log(lat + ", " + lon);

        // I usually put longitude first because I associate vector.x with "horizontal."
        return new Vector2(lon, lat);
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
                Renderer renderer = hit.collider.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                Vector3 offset = hit.collider.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point);
                var longLat = ToSpherical(offset);
                var cart = ConvertGeoToCartesian(longLat[0], longLat[1], radius);
                if (prevHit != null) {
                    DrawCurvedLineOnSphere(prevHit, cart);
                }
                prevHit = cart;
            }
        }
    }
}

The above code draws a line that sort of intersects the sphere and goes to infinity (with alignment transform z). It looks like it might be slighty curved.

I can only get it to appear by dragging the mouse, The behavior I want is just two clicks. It also seems totally unrelated to where I put my mouse, I can't figure out the relationship.
One thing I have noticed after setting the pixel color is that it colors the opposite side of the sphere after getting the pixelUV of the texture from the collider. I'm not sure why this is happening.

                Material mat = renderer.material;
                Texture2D texture2D = mat.mainTexture as Texture2D;

                // Convert hit texture coordinates to pixel coordinates
                Vector2 pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;
                pixelUV.x *= texture2D.width;
                pixelUV.y *= texture2D.height;
                Debug.Log("x: " + pixelUV.x + " y: " + pixelUV.y);

                // Check if texture is readable before modifying pixels
                if (texture2D.isReadable) {
                    // Set pixel color
                    texture2D.SetPixel((int)pixelUV.x, (int)pixelUV.y, Color.red);

                    // Apply pixel changes
                    texture2D.Apply();

                    // Log success
                    Debug.Log("Pixel color set successfully!");
                } else {
                    Debug.LogError("Texture is not readable. Adjust import settings.");
                }


Most readers aren't familiar with GPlates. Can you edit to include something that shows the visual result you're trying to get?
